# Integrate ivy and doxygen

Tags: doxygen, ivy

Is there a way to integrate ivy and doxygen?  I want to publish my doxygen docs through ivy is that possible?  And if so how?  Is there documentation for how to?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a doxygen user. I'm assuming that you're using it to create a zip archive of documents?

Ivy can be used to publish any type of file. The following [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200762/good-ivy-tutorial-for-local-repository/) gives an example of how to publish text files to a local repository. To alternatively publish to a remote repository is only a matter of switching [resolvers](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/resolvers.html)

In previous company, we converted our existing FTP site into an ivy repository by including an *ivy.xml* file with each release (The [vfs](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/vfs.html) resolver supports FTP). This ivy file file became our release descriptor. Internally we used ivy to publish the release and externally customers were now able to [mirror](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/build-repository.html) our files.

Hope it helps.