# Suggestions for big Client/Server project layout and Ivy setup

Tags: c#, java, build, ivy, multilingual

I have a reasonably large (thousands of files) project which is divided between client (100% C#) and server (95% Java with a bit of C#).

I have recently introduced Ivy as a test into the server only and it works fine, fetching dependencies and publishing.  I could have another ivy config/setup for the client but  I should really be publishing the whole server+client together which means there should be one set of Ivy config and one publication step.

I don't see any major roadblocks with using Ivy for the client side, although Ivy is written in Java most of the concepts are general.  And I'm happy enough calling nant from ant to do C# builds (MSBuild).

So with that said does anyone have an experience/suggestions for doing the following

- Using Ivy with a multi-language project
- Using Ivy to pull down multi-language dependencies
- Using Ivy to do multi-language publications under a single version

And any examples would be most useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ivy as a generic dependency manager

You're quite correct, ivy is a generic dependency manager that can manage any artifact.

I've previously provided an example of creating an ivy repository using ivy:

[good ivy tutorial for local repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200762/good-ivy-tutorial-for-local-repository/2279596#2279596)

And here's an example of publishing a zip file to Nexus

[It's possible to put binary files on nexus repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662465/its-possible-to-put-binary-files-on-nexus-repository/3676013#3676013)

### Client and server

My recommendation would be to keep client and server development separated. The client team could have dependencies on libraries produced by the server team, keeping the modules separated allows the teams to work on the latest stable binaries that each published to your repository.

There's nothing stopping you from creating a parent module that has a dependency on both client and server modules.

### Repositories

Ivy is great for managing small repos, however I'd recommend considering a full blown repository manager like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/), [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.org/products.php) or [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/). This enables the local proxying of jars available from the internet (improving performance and reliability) and also provide interfaces for uploading binaries for storage.

On that final point, it is a not so well known fact that Maven repositories can also store artifacts of any type. Maven module POMs contain an optional "packaging" tag that defaults to "jar", but can be any file extension.

So use the best of both worlds! :-)

Comment: Thanks that is useful, however the client/server in my project are consider part of the same project/module so I really want one ivy.xml to handle both so they are both published under one module/version.

Comment: Are you using a Maven repository? Maven has a silly restriction of one artifact per POM, leading to the Parent-child POM nonsense..... Ivy modules on the other hand have no restriction on the number of published artifacts associated with a single module.

Comment: No I'm not using a Maven repo, I built my own (ivy) repo on one of our servers and dropped all the relevant 3rd party dependencies there.  I think I'm getting close to what I want now after a day or two of experimenting.  As you say Ivy is ok with multiple artifacts which works will for me as I have about 10 DLLs and a few jars to publish.