# rsync against a maven nexus repo

Tags: linux, nexus

Is it possible to add and pull files from a sonatype nexus repo using the command line ?

I'm looking at storing the source dir (tarballs and all) of a rpm build environment, and i've been told there's a nexus file repo locally available to do it.

However i've never encountered nexus before so i've no idea how to interact with it. From what i can tell its for java projects, but if it can do the job then im happy enough.

I was kind of hoping i could just rsync the files into a particular dir and nexus will make them known via its web interface.

Comment: Hi there. I think nexus/maven is an inappropriate tool for what you've described. Nexus stores packages & sources as 'jars', which are java-specific, and maven itself has minimal support for building rpms. Something like `yum` or `zypper` would be far better suited to rpm distribution.

Comment: ok. that's more or less what i suspected. its actually the tarballs used for creating rpm's that im looking at storing.

Comment: amir75 ..while the original use was storing jars in the repository expected by Maven this has not be true for a long time and Nexus is a great tool for storing any binary artifacts at this stage.

Answer (score 2):

Check this answer:

[It's possible to put binary files on nexus repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662465/its-possible-to-put-binary-files-on-nexus-repository/3676013#3676013)

The Maven command-line can be used to upload files and once uploaded they can be retrieved using a standard HTTP request.

The Nexus GUI also has a mechanism for a web based file upload.

Answer (score 0):

For a rpm build environment I would suggest you take a look at the [Nexus Yum Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nexus-yum-plugin/). It can expose a repository in Nexus as a Yum repository hosting RPM packages. More documentation is on the site.

In terms of interacting with Nexus it is a just based around a set of [REST API's](https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-core-documentation-plugin/core/docs/index.html) and http requests. So you can script it with anything [including bash and so on](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/01/downloading-artifacts-from-nexus-with-bash/). Or you could write your own plugin as well.

In general Nexus has support for all sorts of artifacts with specific support for .net/NuGet, Eclipse Update Sites (P2), OSGI, Maven sites and of course Maven2 and Maven 1. But as you can see it can be expanded via plugin. I would love for someone to write a plugin that can expose Nexus as an apt-deb/deb repo.

All of this is documented in the [free book about Nexus](http://sonatype.com/index.php/Support/Books/Repository-Management-with-Nexus).

Disclaimer: I do [Nexus related training](http://www.sonatype.com/Services/Training/Nexus-Best-Practices) and did some recent updates on the book.

Comment: its actually tarballs i'd be storing, but they are the source files in the rpm specs. I'll look into the rest of your answer asap.