# installing microsoft sqljdbc driver with maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project and i need to add dependency to Microsoft sqljdbc driver.

I have followed the steps shown in this article [here](http://claude.betancourt.us/add-microsoft-sql-jdbc-driver-to-maven/)

but when i try to do the fist step i get the following error

```
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\soft\sqljdbc_4.1\
enu). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. ->   [Help 1]
```

Comment: Check whether you have the pom.xml

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for the issue. We need to give all the arguments wrapped in double quotas `""` like this

```
mvn install:install-file "-DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver" "-DartifactId=sqljdbc41"  "-Dversion=4.1"  "-Dpackaging=jar" "-Dfile=sqljdbc41.jar"
```

Then only maven will install the file without a `pom` file

Answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348459/maven-3-0-5-command-error-the-goal-you-specified-requires-a-project-to-execute) helped me