# Guidelines for storing binary resources in a maven project

Tags: maven, open-source, sonatype

Is there any guideline about storing binary files in a maven project? I'm working on a project that involves machine learning. The project is OSS and we are going to publish it in [Sonatype OSS repository](https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html). The project includes several pre-trained models that comprises both textual and binary files. We would like to ship these models along with the library itself. Is it fine to simply put models files into `src/main/resources` directory of the project?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it fine to simply put models files into src/main/resources directory of the project?

Yes. However, if these are very large files (considerably larger than the code itself), you may wish to keep them in a separate module (`trained-model-data`, or similar) to isolate it from the code.

If this data changes infrequently, you may also want to version and release it separately from your code, so a new release of your main project wouldn't require a new release of the trained data. That would mean that a bugfix release could just update the code.

Comment: Do you know any project that has such binary data packages?

Comment: Not within a single project. Wherever I've seen this for uploading packaged distributions, or native binaries (e.g. [It's possible to put binary files on nexus repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662465/its-possible-to-put-binary-files-on-nexus-repository)) it's been a one-off upload that's then been used by the main project. Unless your training files are huge, go ahead and include them in the main `.jar`.