# I can't figure out how to use Apache Ivy

Tags: eclipse, apache, jar, ivy

I want to have a JAR file repository on my local network so all other Eclipse users use the same JAR files in Repository for their dependencies. I don't want Maven or Ant, I just want to use Ivy to share my JAR files, how do I do this? which XML file should I use? Can't find a simple solution online.

Comment: The best way to manage a shared repository is to install something like Sonatype Nexus. The alternative is of course ivy which can build and use a repository, but which require a shared ivy settings file. For an example see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200762/good-ivy-tutorial-for-local-repository/2279596#2279596 This example can be expanded to use alternative resolvers like ssh or sftp for operation over a network

Answer (score 0):

For start here is an example of ivy.xml file

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info
        organisation="[your organization]"
        module="your module[for example commons-io]"
        status="integration">
    </info>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="[your jar name]" ext="jar"/>
    </publications>
```

Second an important step is creating an ivy.settings file.

```
<ivysettings>
  <resolvers>
    <filesystem name="public">
      <ivy pattern="/path/to/my/public/rep/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml" />
      <artifact pattern="/path/to/my/public/rep/[organisation]/[module]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
    </filesystem>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

This is just part of the ivy.setting file and the resolver name should represent 
your own repository for publications and downloading jars from your  local network . 
Read more about Adjusting ivy settings on http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/tutorial/defaultconf.html
.
How ever ivy can't do the publish work for you ,and you will have to use ant 
just small build.xml file .
Read on apache site http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/use/publish.html

I hope it will be helpful.